# Ошибка в вк апи AttributeError: 'VkBotMessageEvent' object has no attribute 'user_id' (питон)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Непонятная ошибка с кодом бота ВК.

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import time
import urllib3
import requests
import socket

text='text'

def write_msg(user_id, message, random_id):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id' : random_id})

token = "token"


vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)


longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, 194192081)

try:

    for event in longpoll.listen():

        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:


            request = event.object['text']


            if request == "/text":
                write_msg(event.user_id, text, 0)

except (requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout, socket.timeout, urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Ошибка

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/что-то/Desktop/Untitled-1.py", line 84, in <module>
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': text, 'random_id' : 0})
AttributeError: 'VkBotMessageEvent' object has no attribute 'user_id'
```

Почему-то с `chat_id` такой ошибки не происходит.

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import time
import urllib3
import requests
import socket

text='text'

def write_msg(chat_id, message, random_id):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message': message, 'random_id' : random_id})

token = "token"


vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)


longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, 194192081)

try:

    for event in longpoll.listen():

        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:


            request = event.object['text']


            if request == "/text":
                write_msg(event.chat_id, text, 0)

except (requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout, socket.timeout, urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем проблема и как её решить.

Comment: Какую версию `Long Poll API` Вы используете (посмотреть можно на одноимённой вкладке в настройках сообщества)?

Comment: Vk Long Poll API 5.95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стэктрейс вам говорит, что в классе `VkBotMessageEvent`, который вы вызываете здесь

```
vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': event.user_id, 'message': text, 'random_id' : 0})
```

Отсутствует атрибут `user_id`.

Ссылаясь на исходники vk_api, у данного класса есть атрибут from_user. Попробуйте использовать это или же передать атрибут без указания его названия. В конструкторе from_user - первый.